# How do you map two or more columns into one object?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Using the fluent-nhibernate mappings, I am trying to meet a requirement to create the following and I think I'm just not using the correct keywords in Google...

I have a table and columns:

```
Application
appid, appname, appcode, version-major, version-minor
```

I'd like to map this to an object(s) like so:

```
Application
   Id
   Name
   Code
   Version
      Major
      Minor
```

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Component mapping
http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Wow, thanks! Completely missed that the first time I apparently breezed through that page.